# debugging a google maps api query error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do a simple geocoding query to the google maps api. I am getting a message denied error for seemingly no reason. I see a ton of posts with the same question but I seem to be doing what those weren't and still get the error.

Also adding the sensor parameter at the end results in a denied message whereas having the sensor param as the first gives me zero results. I am obviously doing something stupid. Can someone check please?

I am pasting multiple attempts I did and the results -

1. A HTTP POST attempt -

   ## `curl --data "sensor=false&address=22222" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json`

   {
      "error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
      "results" : [],
      "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
   }
2. Using the example specified in the developer page with sensor param as the first one and XML.

   ## `curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor="false"&address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"`

   `$ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
   `<GeocodeResponse>`
   `<status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>`
   `</GeocodeResponse>`
3. Using the example specified in the developer page with sensor param as the last one.

   ## `curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false`

   $ {
         "error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
         "results" : [],
         "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
     }
4. Another attempt

   ## `curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="22222"&sensor=false`

   $ {
         "error_message" : "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
         "results" : [],
         "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
     }
5. Yet another one.

   ## `curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="22222"`

   $ {
         "results" : [],
         "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
     }

Comment: Turns out this is a curl command line usage error. 

It works if I just put double quotes around the http params like this -- curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"sensor=false&address=22222"

Answer (score 1):

Try double quotes for the whole URL, like this:

```
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=22222&sensor=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to escape the & symbol:

```
curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=22222\&sensor=false
```

which works for me.