# snoopy/curl issue with google maps api

Tags: curl, google-maps-api-3, snoopy

This is related to [debugging a google maps api query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790697/debugging-a-google-maps-api-query-error)

We are using snoopy to do the request and it returns the "sensor must be true or false" problem.

The snoopy generated request is:

> /usr/bin/curl -k -D "/tmp/snodlRoAD" -H "User-Agent: Snoopy v1.2.4" -H
>   "Host: maps.googleapis.com:443" -H "Accept: image/gif,
>   image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*" -H "Content-type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-length: 122" -d
>   "address={encoded address}&sensor=false&key={apikey}&"
>   "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"

If I manually request [as per the known issues]

> curl
>   "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={encoded
>   address}&sensor=false&key={apikey}&"

it works.

But what is the fix for the snoopy generated command line. I have access to the source code to fix the issue if I can get the snoopy formatted request working.

I've posted to the Snoopy group as well but it doesn't seem very active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snoopy generated `curl`, it is doing http `POST` operation(for using `-d` param). Whereas in your working `curl` command, you are using http `GET`. That's why one is working for you, and other one is not.

Sine you have access to the source code, so remove the `-d` param from the command. And append the value of `-d` at the end of the url after `?` mark. Just like your working one.

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={encoded address}&sensor=false&key={apikey}&"
```

Comment: I changed Snoopy from a post to a get. Here is the resultand command it executes: /usr/bin/curl -k -D "/tmp/snoSmiNbI" -H "User-Agent: Snoopy v1.2.4" -H "Host: maps.googleapis.com:443" -H "Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*" "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json\?address={encoded address}\&sensor=false\&key={apikey}" The \ escaping is from escapeshellcmd() which is highly recommended and built into snoopy, but it looks like it's getting re-encoded and passed on to google. The requested URL <code>/maps/api/geocode/json%5C?address=... cannot be found

Comment: Remove `\ ` from the `\?` and `\&` in your url.

Comment: I can't remove it. It's from the escapeshellcmd() and that is a must for security. However, it seems to be a snoopy bug that it wraps the command in quotes, and the wrapping caused the extra escaping. I removed the quoting around the escapeshellcmd and we're good to go. So a combination of a Snoopy bug and a GET vs POST.

Comment: Hm... Then its a problem. Another solution if its possible to do String replace, then just do a String replace after the `escapeshellcmd` operation.